# Regex for striping non alphabetic and non numeric characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Total programming newbie here. In ruby, how would I go about striping the following string of non alphabetic and non numeric characters and then split the string into an array by splitting it through spaces.

Example

```
string = "Honey - a sweet, sticky, yellow fluid made by bees and other insects from nectar collected from flowers."
```

Into this

```
tokenized_string = ["Honey", "a", "sweet", "sticky", "yellow", "fluid", "made", "by", "bees", "and", "other", "insects", "from", "nectar", "collected", "from", "flowers"]
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should show us what you've tried instead of asking us for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use:

```
string = "Honey - a sweet, sticky, yellow fluid made by bees and other insects from nectar collected from flowers."
string.delete('^A-Za-z0-9 ').split 
# => ["Honey",
#     "a",
#     "sweet",
#     "sticky",
#     "yellow",
#     "fluid",
#     "made",
#     "by",
#     "bees",
#     "and",
#     "other",
#     "insects",
#     "from",
#     "nectar",
#     "collected",
#     "from",
#     "flowers"]
```

If you're trying to remove everything but alphanumerics, then the `\w` character class can't be used because it is defined as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, which allows `_` to leak in or squeeze through. Here's an example:

```
'foo_BAR12'[/\w+/] # => "foo_BAR12"
```

That matched the entire string, including `_`.

```
'foo_BAR12'[/[A-Za-z0-9]+/] # => "foo"
```

That stopped at `_`, because the class `[A-Za-z0-9]` doesn't include it.

`\w` should be considered a matching pattern for variable names, NOT for alphanumerics. If you want a character class for alphanumerics, look at the [POSIX `\[\[:alnum:\]\]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html) class:

```
'foo_BAR12'[/[[:alnum:]]+/] # => "foo"
```

Comment: `scan` works too, UNLESS there are embedded non-alphanumerics: `'foo_BAR12'.scan(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/) # => ["foo", "BAR12"]` vs.
`'foo_BAR12'.delete('^A-Za-z0-9 ').split # => ["fooBAR12"]`. Only the OP knows which is right.

Comment: This question, and its answers, are a great example why regular expressions are often *NOT* the correct first choice for solving this sort of problem. A pattern can have very subtle holes in it that allow in false-positives, and can be very difficult to track down and squish. It's important to test them against a lot of text to make sure they behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Do as belowe using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan)

```
string = "Honey - a sweet, sticky, yellow fluid made by bees and other insects from nectar collected from flowers."
string.scan(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)
# => ["Honey",
#     "a",
#     "sweet",
#     "sticky",
#     "yellow",
#     "fluid",
#     "made",
#     "by",
#     "bees",
#     "and",
#     "other",
#     "insects",
#     "from",
#     "nectar",
#     "collected",
#     "from",
#     "flowers"]
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add `.map &:strip`

Comment: Plus a typo like `string = "Honey- a sweet…"` or semicolon in `string = "Honey; a sweet…"` ruins your regexp.

Comment: Don't use `\w`. It doesn't mean "alpha-numberic", it means `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. It's useful for variables, but not for letters and numbers because of `_`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possibilities, e.g.:

```
string.gsub(/\W/) { |m| m if m == ' ' }.split
```

or, even clearer:

```
string.gsub(/\W/) { |m| m if m.strip.empty? }.split
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. The following gives you the array you want without your having to use `split`:

```
string.scan(/\w+/)
```

Play around with it on [Rubular.com](http://rubular.com/).

Comment: The `\w` character class isn't exactly alpha-numeric. The definition is `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. The `_` means `\w+` will match `foo123_BAR`, which isn't what the OP wants since `_` is neither a letter or a number.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks. In this case it will answer the sentence he presented and similar sentences, no?

Comment: You can't count on it. The requirement was to remove non-alphanumerics.